# What part of Hindley-Milner do you not understand?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, hindley-milner, denotational-semantics

I *swear* there used to be a **T-shirt** for sale featuring the immortal words:

---

What part of

[image: Hindley-Milner]

do you *not* understand?

---

In my case, the answer would be... all of it!

In particular, I often see notation like this in Haskell papers, but I have no clue what any of it means. I have no idea what branch of mathematics it's supposed to be.

I recognize the letters of the Greek alphabet of course and symbols such as "∉" (which usually means that something is not an element of a set).

On the other hand, I've never seen "⊢" before ([Wikipedia claims it might mean "partition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)). I'm also unfamiliar with the use of the vinculum here. (Usually, it denotes a fraction, but that does not *appear* to be the case here.)

If somebody could at least tell me where to start looking to comprehend what this sea of symbols means, that would be helpful.

Comment: If you ***are*** looking for a good explanation of the algorithm, the best that I've found so far is in chapter 30 of Shriram Krishnamurthi's [*Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation*](http://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/plai-2007-04-26.pdf) (CC licensed!).

Comment: @laslowh Thank you! I’m reading it. Newer version: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2012/book/book.pdf

Comment: Found the T-shirt! https://www.zazzle.com/hindley_milner_type_inference_t_shirt-235812502357339841

Comment: Oh hey this whole thing was [my idea](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.functional/c/j_BOMuepWwQ/m/4YWu-pYIMooJ)... I didn't make the shirts, though I did buy one.

Answer (score 707, accepted):

- The *horizontal bar* means that "[above] **implies** [below]".
- If there are *multiple expressions* in [above], then consider them **anded** together; all of the [above] must be true in order to guarantee the [below].
- `:` means **has type**
- `∈` means **is in**. (Likewise `∉` means "is not in".)
- `Γ` is usually used to refer to an **environment** or context; in this case it can be thought of as a set of type annotations, pairing an identifier with its type. Therefore `x : σ  ∈ Γ` means that the environment `Γ` includes the fact that `x` has type `σ`.
- `⊢` can be read as **proves** or determines. `Γ ⊢ x : σ` means that the environment `Γ` determines that `x` has type `σ`.
- `,` is a way of **including** specific additional assumptions into an environment `Γ`.
  Therefore, `Γ, x : τ ⊢ e : τ'` means that environment `Γ`, *with the additional, overriding assumption that `x` has type `τ`*, proves that `e` has type `τ'`.

---

As requested: operator precedence, from highest to lowest:

- Language-specific infix and mixfix operators, such as `λ x . e`, `∀ α . σ`, and `τ → τ'`, `let x = e0 in e1`, and whitespace for function application.
- `:`
- `∈` and `∉`
- `,` (left-associative)
- `⊢`
- whitespace separating multiple propositions (associative)
- the horizontal bar

Comment: What are the precedence rules of the operators?

Comment: `:` and `∈` are very similar, in that they mean that one thing is contained in another thing – a set contains elements, and a type contains values, in a sense. The crucial difference is that `x ∈ S` means that a set `S` literally contains an element `x`, whereas `Γ ⊢ x : T` means that `x` can be deduced to inhabit type `T` in context `Γ`. Considering this, the Var rule reads: »If x is literally contained in the context, it can (trivially) be inferred from it«.

Comment: @Randomblue I made explicit the precedence of symbols by adding parentheses everywhere, e.g. `(Γ,(x:τ))⊢(x:σ)`, see https://www.overleaf.com/read/ddmnkzjtnqbd#/61990222/

Answer (score 341):

This syntax, while it may look complicated, is actually fairly simple. The basic idea comes from formal logic: the whole expression is an implication with the top half being the assumptions and the bottom half being the result. That is, if you know that the top expressions are true, you can conclude that the bottom expressions are true as well.

### Symbols

Another thing to keep in mind is that some letters have traditional meanings; particularly, Γ represents the "context" you're in—that is, what the types of other things you've seen are. So something like `Γ ⊢ ...` means "the expression `...` when you know the types of every expression in `Γ`.

The `⊢` symbol essentially means that you can prove something. So `Γ ⊢ ...` is a statement saying "I can prove `...` in a context `Γ`. These statements are also called type judgements.

Another thing to keep in mind: in math, just like ML and Scala, `x : σ` means that `x` has type `σ`. You can read it just like Haskell's `x :: σ`.

### What each rule means

So, knowing this, the first expression becomes easy to understand: if we know that `x : σ ∈ Γ` (that is, `x` has some type `σ` in some context `Γ`), then we know that `Γ ⊢ x : σ` (that is, in `Γ`, `x` has type `σ`). So really, this isn't telling you anything super-interesting; it just tells you how to use your context.

The other rules are also simple. For example, take `[App]`. This rule has two conditions: `e₀` is a function from some type `τ` to some type `τ'` and `e₁` is a value of type `τ`. Now you know what type you will get by applying `e₀` to `e₁`! Hopefully this isn't a surprise :).

The next rule has some more new syntax. Particularly, `Γ, x : τ` just means the context made up of `Γ` and the judgement `x : τ`. So, if we know that the variable `x` has a type of `τ` and the expression `e` has a type `τ'`, we also know the type of a function that takes `x` and returns `e`. This just tells us what to do if we've figured out what type a function takes and what type it returns, so it shouldn't be surprising either.

The next one just tells you how to handle `let` statements. If you know that some expression `e₁` has a type `τ` as long as `x` has a type `σ`, then a `let` expression which locally binds `x` to a value of type `σ` will make `e₁` have a type `τ`. Really, this just tells you that a let statement essentially lets you expand the context with a new binding—which is exactly what `let` does!

The `[Inst]` rule deals with sub-typing. It says that if you have a value of type `σ'` and it is a sub-type of `σ` (`⊑` represents a partial ordering relation) then that expression is *also* of type `σ`.

The final rule deals with generalizing types. A quick aside: a free variable is a variable that is not introduced by a let-statement or lambda inside some expression; this expression now depends on the value of the free variable from its context.The rule is saying that if there is some variable `α` which is *not* "free" in anything in your context, then it is safe to say that any expression whose type you know `e : σ` will have that type for *any* value of `α`.

### How to use the rules

So, now that you understand the symbols, what do you do with these rules? Well, you can use these rules to figure out the type of various values. To do this, look at your expression (say `f x y`) and find a rule that has a conclusion (the bottom part) that matches your statement. Let's call the thing you're trying to find your "goal". In this case, you would look at the rule that ends in `e₀ e₁`. When you've found this, you now have to find rules proving everything above the line of this rule. These things generally correspond to the types of sub-expressions, so you're essentially recursing on parts of the expression. You just do this until you finish your proof tree, which gives you a proof of the type of your expression.

So all these rules do is specify exactly—and in the usual mathematically pedantic detail :P—how to figure out the types of expressions.

Now, this should sound familiar if you've ever used Prolog—you're essentially computing the proof tree like a human Prolog interpreter. There is a reason Prolog is called "logic programming"! This is also important as the first way I was introduced to the H-M inference algorithm was by implementing it in Prolog. This is actually surprisingly simple and makes what's going on clear. You should certainly try it.

Note: I probably made some mistakes in this explanation and would love it if somebody would point them out. I'll actually be covering this in class in a couple of weeks, so I'll be more confident then :P.

Comment: \alpha is a non-free type variable, not a usual variable. So to explain generalization rule much more must be explained.

Comment: @nponeccop: Hmm, good point. I haven't actually seen that particular rule before. Could you help me explain it properly?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: It's actually pretty straightforward, it allows you to generalize (assuming `Γ = {x : τ}`) `λy.x : σ → τ` to `∀ σ. σ → τ`, but not to `∀ τ. σ → τ`, because `τ` is free variable in `Γ`. Wikipedia article on [HM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner#Free_type_variables) explains it quite nicely.

Comment: I believe the part of the answer related to `[Inst]` is a bit inaccurate. This is only my understanding so far, but the sigmas in the `[Inst]` and `[Gen]` rules don't refer to types, but to **type-schemes**. So the `⊑` operator is a partial ordering unrelated to sub-typing as we know it from OO languages. It's related to polymorphic values such as `id = λx. x`. The full syntax for such a function would be `id = ∀x. λx. x`. Now, we can obviously have an `id2 = ∀xy. λx. x`, where `y` is not used. Then `id2 ⊑ id`, which is what the `[Inst]` rule says.

Answer (score 76):

> if somebody could at least tell me where to start looking to comprehend what this sea of symbols means

See "[**Practical Foundations of Programming Languages.**](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf)", chapters 2 and 3, on the style of logic through judgements and derivations. The entire book is [now available on Amazon.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107150302)

### Chapter 2

## Inductive Definitions

Inductive definitions are an indispensable tool in the study of programming languages. In this chapter we will develop the basic framework of inductive definitions, and give some examples of their use. An inductive definition consists of a set of *rules* for deriving *judgments*, or *assertions*, of a variety of forms. Judgments are statements about one or more syntactic objects of a specified sort. The rules specify necessary and sufficient conditions for the validity of a judgment, and hence fully determine its meaning.

#### 2.1 Judgments

We start with the notion of a *judgment*, or *assertion* about a syntactic object. We shall make use of many forms of judgment, including examples such as these:

- *n* **nat** — *n* is a natural number
- *n* = *n1* + *n2* — *n* is the sum of *n1* and *n2*
- *τ* **type** — *τ* is a type
- *e* : *τ* — expression *e* has type *τ*
- *e* ⇓ *v* — expression *e* has value *v*

A judgment states that one or more syntactic objects have a property or stand in some relation to one another. The property or relation itself is called a *judgment form*, and the judgment that an object or objects have that property or stand in that relation is said to be an *instance* of that judgment form. A judgment form is also called a *predicate*, and the objects constituting an instance are its *subjects*. We write *a* **J** for the judgment asserting that **J** holds of *a*. When it is not important to stress the subject of the judgment, (text cuts off here)

Answer (score 74):

### How do I understand the Hindley-Milner rules?

Hindley-Milner is a set of rules in the form of [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) (not natural deduction) that demonstrates that we can deduce the (most general) type of a program from the construction of the program without explicit type declarations.

#### The symbols and notation

First, let's explain the symbols, and discuss operator precedence

- is an identifier (informally, a variable name).
- **:** means is a type of (informally, an instance of, or "is-a").
- (sigma) is an expression that is either a variable or function.
- thus **:** is read " is-a "
- ∈ means "is an element of"
- (Gamma) is an environment.
- **⊦** (the assertion sign) means [asserts](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095429606) (or proves, but contextually "asserts" reads better.)
- ⊦  **:**  is thus read " asserts that , is-a "
- is an actual instance (element) of type .
- (tau) is a type: either basic, variable (), functional **→'**, or product **×'** (product is not used here)
- **→'** is a functional type where   and **'** are potentially different types.
- **.** means  (lambda) is an anonymous function that takes an argument, , and returns an expression, .
- **let**  **= ₀** **in** **₁** means in expression, **₁**, substitute **₀** wherever  appears.
- **⊑** means the prior element is a subtype (informally - subclass) of the latter element.
- is a type variable.
- ∀ **.** is a type, ∀ (for all) argument variables, , returning  expression
- ∉ **free()** means not an element of the free type variables of  defined in the outer context. (Bound variables are substitutable.)

Everything above the line is the premise, everything below is the conclusion ([Per Martin-Löf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecrary/819-f09/Martin-Lof83.pdf))

#### Precedence, by example

I have taken some of the more complex examples from the rules and inserted redundant parentheses that show precedence:

- **:**  ∈  could be written **( : )** ∈
- ⊦  **:**  could be written  ⊦ ( **:** )
- ⊦ **let**  **= ₀** **in** **₁** : 
  is equivalently
   ⊦ ((**let** ( **= ₀**) **in** **₁**) : )
- ⊦ **.** : **→'** is equivalently  ⊦ ((**.**) : (**→'**))

Then, large spaces separating assertion statements and other preconditions indicates a set of such preconditions, and finally the horizontal line separating premise from conclusion brings up the end of the precedence order.

### The Rules

What follows here are English interpretations of the rules, each followed by a loose restatement and an explanation.

#### Variable

[image: VAR Logic Diagram]

> Given  is a type of  (sigma), an element of  (Gamma),
> conclude  asserts  is a .

Put another way, in , we know  is of type  because  is of type  in .

This is basically a tautology. An identifier name is a variable or a function.

#### Function Application

[image: APP Logic Diagram]

> Given  asserts ₀ is a functional type and  asserts ₁ is a 
> conclude  asserts applying function ₀ to ₁ is a type '

To restate the rule, we know that function application returns type ' because the function has type →' and gets an argument of type .

This means that if we know that a function returns a type, and we apply it to an argument, the result will be an instance of the type we know it returns.

#### Function Abstraction

[image: ABS Logic Diagram]

> Given  and  of type  asserts  is a type, '
> conclude  asserts an anonymous function,  of  returning expression,  is of type →'.

Again, when we see a function that takes  and returns an expression , we know it's of type →' because  (a ) asserts that  is a '.

If we know  is of type  and thus an expression  is of type ', then a function of  returning expression  is of type →'.

#### Let variable declaration

[image: LET Logic Diagram]

> Given  asserts ₀, of type , **and**  and , of type , asserts ₁ of type 
> conclude  asserts `let` =₀ `in` ₁ of type

Loosely,  is bound to ₀ in ₁ (a ) because ₀ is a , and  is a  that asserts ₁ is a .

This means if we have an expression ₀ that is a  (being a variable or a function), and some name, , also a , and an expression ₁ of type , then we can substitute ₀ for  wherever it appears inside of ₁.

#### Instantiation

[image: INST Logic Diagram]

> Given  asserts  of type ' and ' is a subtype of 
> conclude  asserts  is of type

An expression,  is of parent type  because the expression  is subtype ', and  is the parent type of '.

If an instance is of a type that is a subtype of another type, then it is also an instance of that super-type - the more general type.

#### Generalization

[image: GEN Logic Diagram]

> Given  asserts  is a  **and**  is not an element of the free variables of ,
> conclude  asserts , type for all argument expressions  returning a  expression

So in general,  is typed  for all argument variables () returning , because we know that  is a  and  is not a free variable.

This means we can generalize a program to accept all types for arguments not already bound in the containing scope (variables that are not non-local). These bound variables are substitutable.

### Putting it all together

Given certain assumptions (such as no free/undefined variables, a known environment, ) we know the types of:

- atomic elements of our programs (Variable),
- values returned by functions (Function Application),
- functional constructs (Function Abstraction),
- let bindings (Let Variable Declarations),
- parent types of instances (Instantiation), and
- all expressions (Generalization).

### Conclusion

These rules combined allow us to prove the most general type of an asserted program, without requiring type annotations.

Answer (score 49):

The notation comes from [natural deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction).

⊢ symbol is called [turnstile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29).

The 6 rules are very easy.

`Var` rule is rather trivial rule - it says that if type for identifier is already present in your type environment, then to infer the type you just take it from the environment as is.

`App` rule says that if you have two identifiers `e0` and `e1` and can infer their types, then you can infer the type of application `e0 e1`. The rule reads like this if you know that `e0 :: t0 -> t1` and `e1 :: t0` (the same t0!), then application is well-typed and the type is `t1`.

`Abs` and `Let` are rules to infer types for lambda-abstraction and let-in.

`Inst` rule says that you can substitute a type with less general one.

Comment: This is sequent calculus, not natural deduction.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka well, the notation is much the same. The wikipedia article has an interesting comparison of the two techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Sequent_calculus . The sequent calculus was born in direct response to the failings of natural deduction, so if the question is "where did this notation come from", then "natural deduction" is technically a more correct answer.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka Another consideration is that sequent calculus is purely syntactic (that's why there are so many structural rules) while this notation is not. The first rule assumes that context is a set while in sequent calculus it's a simpler syntactic construct.

Comment: @Cheplyaka actually, no, it has something that looks like a "sequent" but it is not sequent calculus.  Haper develops an understanding of this in his text book as a "higher order judgment."  This really is natural deduction.

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to think of e : σ. One is "the expression e has type σ", another is "the ordered pair of the expression e and the type σ".

View Γ as the knowledge about the types of expressions, implemented as a set of pairs of expression and type, e : σ.

The turnstile ⊢ means that from the knowledge on the left, we can deduce what's on the right.

The first rule [Var] can thus be read:
If our knowledge Γ contains the pair e : σ, then we can deduce from Γ that e has type σ.

The second rule [App] can be read:
If we from Γ can deduce that e_0 has the type τ → τ', and we from Γ can deduce that e_1 has the type τ, then we from Γ can deduce that e_0 e_1 has the type τ'.

It's common to write Γ, e : σ instead of Γ ∪ {e : σ}.

The third rule [Abs] can thus be read:
If we from Γ extended with x : τ can deduce that e has type τ', then we from Γ can deduce that λx.e has the type τ → τ'.

The fourth rule [Let] is left as an exercise. :-)

The fifth rule [Inst] can be read:
If we from Γ can deduce that e has type σ', and σ' is a subtype of σ, then we from Γ can deduce that e has type σ.

The sixth and last rule [Gen] can be read:
If we from Γ can deduce that e has type σ, and α is not a free type variable in any of the types in Γ, then we from Γ can deduce that e has type ∀α σ.

Comment: Re the fifth rule, `[Inst]` - you said this rule is about subtyping. Subtyping is not part of traditional Hindley-Milner, instead Inst rule is about replacing type variables with monotypes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Type_order.