# Is the compiler smart enough to infer a parsed value's type based on the value's usage in a function which expects that type?

Tags: parsing, rust, type-inference

I found this code on [the tokio hello world page](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/):

```
fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:6142".parse().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();

    // Following snippets come here...
}
```

Is the Rust compiler actually smart enough to infer that the type that the string holding the IP address should be parsed to is `std::net::SocketAddr` because the parsed variable is passed to the bind method which expects that type? Why don't you need to [use the turbofish operator (::<>) or an explicit type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int-in-rust)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* smart enough to use later usage of a variable to infer its type in the first place. The same could be seen in an extremely simple example:

```
fn foo(v: Vec<i16>) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![]; // Let's make a Vec<_>
    numbers.push(12345);      // Let's push a number (of an unknown type) to it
    foo(numbers);             // A-ha! It is passed to a function requiring a Vec<i16>. 
                              // That means `numbers` is Vec<i16>
                              // and the constant 12345 is of type i16.
}
```

See also [How does Rust's type inference work across multiple statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542971/how-does-rusts-type-inference-work-across-multiple-statements)