# Why does Rust fail to correctly infer the type?

Tags: rust

Why does this work fine:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
let mut cumulator = 0;

for next in items.iter() {
    cumulator += next;
}

println!("Final {}", cumulator);
```

But this fail?:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
let mut cumulator = 0;

for next in items.iter() {
    cumulator += next.pow(2);
}

println!("Final {}", cumulator);
```

Error on `.pow(2)`:

```
no method named `pow` found for reference `&{integer}` in the current scope
method not found in `&{integer}`rustc (E0599)
```

My IDE identifies `next` as i32 and the first code example works fine. But the compiler has an issue the moment I reference `next.pow()` or any function on `next` . The compiler complains that `next` is an ambiguous integer type.

Sure, I can fix this by either explicitly declaring the array as `i32[]`. Or I can also use an interim variable before `cumulator` which is also explicitly declared `i32`. But these seem unnecessary and a bit clunky.

So why is compiler happy in the first case and not in the second?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542971/how-does-rusts-type-inference-work-across-multiple-statements#37573432 for an explanation of Rust's type inference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling methods *on* objects is kind of funny, because it conveys zero information. That is, if I write

```
a + b
```

Then, even if Rust knows nothing about `a` and `b`, it can now assume that `a` is `Add` where the `Rhs` type is the type of `b`. We can refine the types and, hopefully, get more information down the road. Similarly, if I write `foobar()`, where `foobar` is a local variable, then Rust knows it has to be at least `FnOnce`.

However, if `foo` is a variable, and I write

```
foo.frobnicate()
```

Then Rust has *no* idea what to do with that. Is it an inherent `impl` on some type? Is it a trait function? It could be *literally* anything. If it's inherent, then it could even be in a module that we haven't imported, so we can't simply check everything that's in scope.

In your case, [`pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=pow) isn't even a trait function, it's actually several different functions. Even if it *was* a trait function, we couldn't say anything, because we don't, a priori, know *which* trait. So Rust sees `next.pow(2)` and bails out immediately, rather than trying to do something unexpected.

In your other case, Rust is able to infer the type. At the end of the function, all it knows about the type is that it's an `{integer}` on which `Add` is defined, and Rust has [integer defaulting](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0212-restore-int-fallback.md) rules that kick in to turn that into `i32`, in the absence of any other information.

Could they have applied integer defaulting to `next.pow(2)`? Possibly, but I'm glad they didn't. Integers are already a special case in Rust (integers and floats are the only types with polymorphic literals), so minimizing the amount of special casing required by the compiler is, at least in my mind, a good thing. The defaulting rules kicked in in the first example because nothing caused it to bail out, and they would have in the second if it hadn't already encountered the bigger error condition of "calling an `impl` function on an unknown type".