# How to comfortably deal with the type system on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-inference, type-systems

Haskell's type system is powerful and liked for its mathematical rigorousness and logical soundness, on the other side something as naive as below makes me wonder why it doesn't work as expected by intuition?

E.g. why can't `Int` be converted to `Num` on `x3` but `f1` accept `Int` against the signature `Num`?

```
Prelude> let x1 = 1
Prelude> :t x1
x1 :: Num a => a

Prelude> let x2 = 1 :: Int
Prelude> :t x2
x2 :: Int

Prelude> let x3 = (1 :: Int) :: Num a => a
Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘Int’

Prelude> let f1 :: Num a => a -> a; f1 = id
Prelude> :t f1 (1 :: Int)
f1 (1 :: Int) :: Int

Prelude> let f2 :: Int -> Int; f2 = id
Prelude> :t f2 1
f2 1 :: Int

Prelude> let f3 :: Num a => a -> Int; f3 = id

Prelude> let f4 :: Num a => Int -> a; f4 = id
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’
```

I knew that one should finally learn the underlying theory e.g. [HM type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) to comfortably deal with the type system, and even found some nice writings e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532552/what-part-of-milner-hindley-do-you-not-understand), [2](http://akgupta.ca/blog/2013/05/14/so-you-still-dont-understand-hindley-milner/), [3](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/006_hindley_milner.html) and [4](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/seminar/sove/SS2013/final/hindley-milner.slides.pdf) for demystifying it. What else would you like to recommend if you ever came cross and overcame this challenge?

**@EDIT**

```
Prelude> let f5 x5 = x5::Int
Prelude> :t f5
f5 :: Int -> Int

Prelude> let f6 x6 = x6::Num a => a
Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘t’
```

First, `x6` must have been a supertype of `Num` that is `Num` itself when `x6` is type annotated with `Num`. However, the concatenate type annotations for `Num` after `Int` of `(x6::Int)::Num a => a` won't be united if we then downcast `x6` from `Num` to `Int`. Hence,
the first inferred type `Num` of `x6` is unsatisfied here.

Comment: "why it doesn't work as expected by intuition?" -- The million dollar question here is: *which* intuition? (Fortunately, it is not at all necessary to formally understand Hindley-Milner to get comfortable with your examples. Perhaps it is more a question of getting rid of some preconceptions, as I predict the forthcoming answers will demonstrate.)

Comment: Your confusion seems to be with type classes and not so much with Hindley-Milner.

Comment: I have a super-secret type, an instance of `Num`, called `TomsAwesomeNumType`.  Your `f3` type signature says that, despite not knowing anything else about my type, you can convert it to an `Int`.  Your `f4` signature says that despite this lack of knowledge you can convert any `Int` to my super secret type (or any other type that is an instance of Num).  Your implementations, on the other hand, are another issue I'll leave to whomever answers.

Comment: From OOP's perspective let's take `Java` to compare `f2`. Assuming `Number x2 = new Integer(1);`, `f2(x2)` won't work straightly; instead, we have to explicitly subcast `x2` then `f2((Integer)x2)` does. This kind of discrepancy makes me wonder how the type system on `Haskell` rolls, thus `Typeclass` and `HM` etc.

Comment: The key point is that it rolls in a very different way from OOP. Hopefully my answer will help to clarify that.

Comment: The closest Java concept is generic methods. `f1 :: Num a => a -> a` could something like `<A extends Num> A f1(A a1, A a2)` where `Num` is some interface. Crucially, in Haskell you can never have a variable of type `Num` since that's not a type in Haskell, unlike Java. In Haskell, you can use `Num a` only to constrain universal quantification like the Java `<A extends Num>`.

Comment: @chi: It would be just `<A extends Num> A f1(A)`, but your point stands.

Comment: @JonPurdy Oops. Right, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> why can't `Int` be converted to `Num` on `x3`

1. `Int` cannot be converted to `Num` because `Int` is a type and `Num` is a *type class*. The difference between these two kinds of entities will hopefully become clear in what follows.
2. `Int` cannot be converted to anything else because Haskell has no conversions in the sense you are using here. There are no implicit casts. What does happen is a polymorphic type getting *specialised* to some definite type; however, a definite type never becomes something else automatically.

With that in mind, let's consider your examples.

```
Prelude> let x1 = 1
Prelude> :t x1
x1 :: Num a => a
```

`x1` here is *polymorphic*, which means it can assume different types depending on how you use it. This indeterminacy can be recognised by the presence of the type variable `a` (type variables, unlike concrete types, are not capitalised). The type of `x1`, though polymorphic, is to some extent restricted by the *constraint* `Num a`. `Num a => a` can be read as "any type that has an instance of the *type class* `Num`", while a plain `a` would mean "any type whatsoever".

```
Prelude> let x2 = 1 :: Int
Prelude> :t x2
x2 :: Int
```

Introducing the type annotation `:: Int` means requesting `Int` to be *unified* with the type of `1`, `Num a => a`. In this case, that simply means replacing the type variable `a` with `Int`. Given that `Int` does have an instance of `Num`, that is a valid move, and the type checker happily accepts it. The type annotation *specialises* the polymorphic type of `1` to `Int`.

```
Prelude> let x3 = (1 :: Int) :: Num a => a
Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘Int’
```

The type of `1 :: Int` is `Int`. The second annotation demands unifying it with `Num a => a`. That, however, is impossible. Once a type is specialised, you can't "forget" the type and revert the specialisation just by providing a type annotation. Perhaps you are thinking of OOP upcasting; this is not at all the same thing. By the way, if the type checker accepted `x3`, you would be able to write `x4 = ((1 :: Int) :: Num a => a) :: Double`, thus converting an `Int` to a `Double`. In the general case, though, there is no way this conversion can happen like that, as you didn't tell *how* the conversion is to be done; as for the special cases, there aren't any. (Converting an `Int` to a `Double` is certainly possible, but it requires an appropriate function. For instance, you may find it relevant to consider how the type of `fromIntegral` relates to what it does.)

```
Prelude> let f1 :: Num a => a -> a; f1 = id
Prelude> :t f1 (1 :: Int)
f1 (1 :: Int) :: Int
```

The principles here remain the same. The only difference is that you have to consider how the types of argument and result are related to each other. The type of `id` is `a -> a`. It specialises just fine to `Num a => a -> a`. Passing an `Int` argument further specialises it to `Int -> Int`, and so you get a result of type `Int`.

```
Prelude> let f2 :: Int -> Int; f2 = id
Prelude> :t f2 1
f2 1 :: Int
```

`f1` had a polymorphic type that you specialised by feeding it an `Int` argument, while `f2` has a monomorphic type, and so there is no need to specialise it. `id` is specialised from `a -> a` directly to `Int -> Int`, while `1` is specialised from `Num a => a` to `Int` because you are feeding it to a function that expects an `Int` argument.

```
Prelude> let f3 :: Num a => a -> Int; f3 = id
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’
```

Here, you want to unify `a -> a`, the type of `id`, with `Num a => a -> Int`. However, if you replace `a` with, for instance, `Double` in `Num a => a -> Int`, you get `Double -> Int`, which can't possibly unify with `a -> a`, because it changes types while `a -> a` doesn't. (That is the point of Thomas M. DuBuisson's comment above: the type of your implementations is not compatible with that of `id`, because `id` can't change the type of anything.)

```
Prelude> let f4 :: Num a => Int -> a; f4 = id
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’
```

Finally, this is just like `f3`, except that the mismatch happens on the result type rather than on that of the argument. Putting a different spin on it this time, you can't implement a `Num a => Int -> a` function by settling on a specific type with a `Num` instance (be it `Int`, `Double`, etc.) and then "upcasting" it to `Num a => a`, because there is no such thing as upcasting. Rather `Num a => Int -> a` must work for *any* choice of `a` whatsoever that has an instance of `Num`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Not only does it help clarify this very puzzle but also conveys the keywords such as `polymorphic, constraint, typeclass, typevar, monomorphic, instance, type, specializing, unification` that shed light on my further quest for knowing the type system on Haskell better.

Comment: One follow-up question, a monomorphic typed value is trival to define, e.g. `data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT`; how is a polymorphic typed value defined such as the number  `1`?

Comment: @sof [1/2] A typical polymorphic (algebraic) data type can be defined much in the same manner. In `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`, the `Just` constructor can be used to wrap a value of arbitrary type. `Maybe` on its own is an example of a *type constructor*, because it makes a different type out of an existing one (e.g. from `Int` to `Maybe Int`).

Comment: @sof [2/2] Numbers are different, though. The trick is that, for instance, `1` actually stands for `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)`. `Integer` is used as a "default" type for integer literals, and `fromInteger` (which is a method of `Num`) is used to convert to the appropriate type. That is specified by [Section 6.4.1 of the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4). As for what `Integer, `Double`, etc. are under the hood, implementations are free to use whatever is convenient/efficient as long as it meets the Report spec.

Comment: thanks. I can follow your comment [1/2] that described the so called `parametric polymorphic` typed value. [2/2] is about `ad-hoc polymorphic` aka `overloading`, right? Does it mean that the numeric literal `1` is recognized thus translated into `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)` by the compiler? Are overloaded values restricted in built-in constructs? How to make a user defined version if allowed too?  Sorry for the lengthy follow-ups, hopefully they will complement your applauded answer perfectly.

Comment: @sof Adding more polymorphic literal constructs is a matter for language extensions (for instance, `OverloadedStrings` is a commonly used GHC extension, and there is also `OverloadedLists`), though there is always the option of simulating a syntax extension through Template Haskell (i.e. compile-time meta programming). (In any case, if you have a `Foo` type that you have defined and a function `fromFoo :: FooLike a => Foo -> a`, you can use `fromFoo` for overloaded creation of values, and only the syntactical convenience of the literals would be missing in comparison with the `Num` example.)