# Misconception on Type Classes and variable assignment in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, variable-assignment, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism

Very new to Haskell and trying to understand how type classes and variables interact.

My first thing to play with was:

```
i :: a; i = 1
```

My expectation was that, since i was typed as generically as possible, I should be able to assign absolutely anything to it.  (I know that I probably can't do anything with variable i, but that wasn't important.)

But, I was wrong.  The above gives an error and requires that it be:

```
i :: Num a => a; i = 1
```

After playing around a bit more I came up with the following:

```
g :: Num a => a -> a; g a = a + 1
g 1
(returned 2)
gg :: Num a => a; gg = g 1
gg
(returned 2)
```

Ok... so far so good.  Let's try a Fractional parameter.

```
g :: Num a => a -> a; g a = a + 1
g 1.3
(returned 2.3)
gg :: Num a => a; gg = g 1.3
(error)
```

So, please... what is it about variables that causes this?  From a non-functional programming background, it "looks" like I have a function that returns a value with a type implementing Num and tried to assign it to a variable with a type implementing Num.  Yet, the assignment fails.

I'm sure this is some basic misconception I have.  It's probably the same thing that prevents the first example from working. I really want to get it straightened out before I start making far more serious conceptual errors.

Comment: Since you write `g 1.3`, that means the type is more "restricted", `gg` has as type `gg :: Fractional a => a`. Note however that (unless in some rare cases), you should not type variables, Haskell will always use the most generic type possible. You do not *assign* values to a variable, you declare a variable: once you assigned a value, you can never change it value again.

Comment: Related: [*How to comfortably deal with the type system on Haskell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432690/2751851)

Comment: I'm not getting it.  Sorry.  The first part of :i Fractional is "class Num a => Fractional a".  Doesn't that mean that a Fractional implements type class Num?  Or, is it that I'm confusing myself over functions and variables.  A function argument has to implement specific type classes, but a variable can only accept certain types?

How would I type a variable to receive the result from g?  Just from the type definition of g?

Just saw your edit... I was wondering if typing variables was a bad move.  I guess it is.

Comment: @MarcL.Allen: it is correct that for a type in order to be a member of the `Fractional` typeclass, it needs to be a member of the `Num` typeclass, hence that means that `Fractional` is more "*specific*" than the `Num` typeclass, since more members (like `Int`) can be a member of the `Num` typeclass, but *not* of the `Fractional` typeclass.

Comment: @MarcL.Allen: typing variables is not a bad move, typically top level variables are typed in a Haskell code fragment. It however looks like you think it is some sort of "variable declaration" like in Java, etc. like `int i; i = 2`, it is not.

Comment: Short answer: "generic" doesn't mean "untyped".

Comment: before the types even, *`=` is **not** assignment. it is **definition***.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not going to make a big deal over it, but I don't really think this is a duplicate question.  My question deals more with the misconception of what "typing a variable" means.  While the linked question does, in all the other information it provides, include answers to this question, the two questions really are not the same.

Comment: @MarcL.Allen The rule of thumb I use is that if two questions generate the same answer then they're duplicates, even if they're not exactly the same wording. When I read this question, my instinct was to write up the "types as protocols" view again, since it perfectly explains what's going on; therefore I consider these two questions to generate the same answer. (It's just luck that you were asking specifically about `Num` and `Fractional`, like the linked question.) See also the [When are two questions considered duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841) discussion on meta-SO.

Comment: @DanielWagner Understood.  However, from the third paragraph under "When are two questions considered duplicate", I believe these questions are merely related, even if you were thinking of using the same answer.  Your answer answers far more than either question asked, so it's not surprising that it can be used for different questions.

Comment: @MarcL.Allen I too thought your question was more about the essence of [tag:parametric-polymorphism], than specifically type classes. but there's plenty duplicates for it under that view as well. I'll try to find some links, but you might as well just search / browse the tag itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> i :: a; i = 1
> ```
>
> My expectation was that, since i was typed as generically as possible, I should be able to assign absolutely anything to it. (I know that I probably can't do anything with variable i, but that wasn't important.)

No, it's the other way around. The type represents how that value *can be used* later on, i.e. it states that the user can use `i` pretending that it is of any type that might be required at that time. Essentially, the user chooses what the type `a` actually is, and the code defining `i :: a` must conform to any such choice of the user.

(By the way we usually call `i = 1` "binding" or "definition", not "assignment" since that would imply we can reassign later on.)

> ```
> gg :: Num a => a; gg = g 1.3
> (error)
> ```

The same principle applies here. `gg` claims to be of any numeric type the user might want, but if the user later on chooses, say, `Int` the definition `g 1.3` does not fit `Int`.

The user can choose the type using an explicit signature (`print (gg :: Int)`), or putting it into  context that "forces" the type (`print (length "hello" + gg)` forces `Int` since `length` returns `Int`).

If you are familiar with "generics" in some other languages, you can draw a comparison with this code:

```
-- Haskell
i :: a
i = 1            -- type error

-- pseudo-Java
<A> A getI() {
  return 1;      -- type error
}
```

From a more theoretical perspective, you are thinking of the wrong quantifier. When you write `i :: a`, you are thinking `i :: exists a . a` (not a real Haskell type) which reads as "`i` is a value of some type (chosen at definition time)". Instead in Haskell `i :: a` means `i :: forall a . a` which reads as "`i` is a value of all types (any type that might be needed on use)". Hence it boils down to "exists" vs "forall", or to "who chooses what type type `a` actually is".

Comment: Oh.. OH!  Wait a sec... epiphany may be coming....

Comment: So... `i :: a` implies that I could plug `i` into any function regardless of its requirements?  That `i :: a` says that `i` implements every possible type class? (EDIT: This seems to match with your forall edit)

Comment: @MarcL.Allen Roughly, yes. It means that `i` can be used where you need an `Int`, a `Bool`, a `String`, a `Maybe [(Int, Bool)] -> Char`, or any other type. For type classes: if a type class is not empty, i.e. there is some type `T` implementing the methods of the class (`instance C T where ...`) then `i` can be used as a value of `T`. Note that values belong to types, and types belong to type classes.

Comment: @MarcL.Allen Yes, `i :: a` implies that I could plug `i` into any function regardless of its requirements. As for "`i :: a` says that `i` implements every possible type class", on that one I give a resounding "sort of". The statement holds the kernel of truth, I think, but your phrasing seems a bit off; whether a thing is in a type class or not is a property of *types*, but `i` is a computation, not a type.

Comment: @DanielWagner Not surprised... still early enough in the learning process that my language will be imprecise due to misunderstanding the finer points (e.g. assignment vs. definition)

Comment: @DanielWagner can we perhaps always use "calculation" for pure Haskell values (following [Wadler](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/wadler87.pdf) following [Turner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Recursive_Calculator)), and reserve "computation" for monadic values (following [Moggi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenio_Moggi))? an inconsistent terminology is one of reasons ppl can have hard time learning Haskell.

Comment: assignment/definition distinction is the key. with *assignment*, OP's expectations would be entirely reasonable. but since we *define* a *value* (and use a name only to refer to that value), *type* is the *value's* attribute, not the name's.

Comment: @WillNess I can't agree more, especially with your first comment. For instance, it seems to me that "variables" (that I think you are referring to as "pure Haskell values") are nothing more than Haskell functions that take no arguments. Now, that may also not be correct, but I think it's closer than "variables."  Had I known that, this and other questions may have been avoided entirely.

Comment: no, no. there's lots of stuff, from the big guns too, on how Haskell's values are *not* nullary functions. If anything I'd prefer "names" instead of variables, or "named values", or "bindings". But "variables" are fine too. In math they are too known as variables, and are constant, as well. --- re: pure values, *everything* is a pure value in Haskell. `x = 7+8` and `y = print x` both are. But @Daniel's point was, because of laziness, `x` is not immediately a value -- there's a whole *calculation* laying in wait behind it. (that's what you too were referring to, I believe). 1/

Comment: He just used that other word which I'd much rather see used exclusively for the `print x`-like stuff. I.e. potentially "effectful" stuff. The distinction is subtle, `Maybe Int` is pure either way, it's just our interpretation of it that changes. But with `IO` the distinction is real. `print x` is an `IO ()` value denoting an I/O *computation*. that's what I meant. (and I gave links supporting these terminology choices) /2