# How do I find out the type of a haskell expression without ghci?

Tags: haskell, lambda, type-inference, typing, lambda-calculus

I'm pretty good at inferring the type of a lambda expression as long as it does not have any weird functions such as `map`, `filter`, `foldr` or any compositions in it. However, as soon as I have something like

```
\x y -> map x (y (. x))
```

I get totally lost and can't for the life of me figure out how to find out the type without using ghci.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: By doing the type inference yourself. Can you share your attempt?

Comment: I try to rewrite the expression like so : \x y z -> map x (y (x.z)) then \x y z -> map x (y ( (.) x z)) then I try to infer the type of the expression inside the parenthesis but I fail at that.

Comment: Well you can not perform such rewrpite, since it is `(. x)`, which is short for `\z -> (.) z x`, so the rewrite is `\x y -> map x (y (\z -> (.) z x))`.

Comment: Well, start from the outermost function which is `map`. Its type is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and you know that `x` has type of `a -> b` and `y (. x)` has type of `[a]`. Then repeat with `y`.

Comment: could you please elaborate some more? The (. x) gives me the most trouble. I think I should figure the type of y out after that?

Comment: What part of [Hindley-Milner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkKgE.png) don't you understand? ([Tongue firmly in cheek.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12532552/791604))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it by "weird" you pretty much mean higher order functions. This expression contains two: `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. It is also a lambda, so likely a higher order function itself. Each parenthesized arrow here is the type of a function parameter.

`map` reveals that `y` must return a list of items that `x` accepts as an argument. So they have the partial signatures `x :: _yitem -> _outeritem` and `y :: _yarg -> [_yitem]`, where the return value of this `map` is of type `[_outeritem]`. Note that we don't know yet how many arrows fit in these wildcards.

`(. x)` translates to `\l -> l . x` which translates to `\l r -> l (x r)`. This entire lambda is an argument that fits `y`, so `y` is a higher order function. `l` must accept the return value from `x`. That has a name, so `l :: _outeritem -> _lret`, and `(. x) :: (_outeritem -> _lret) -> _xarg -> _lret`, since `r` is used as the argument for `x`. Oh, and `_xarg` is known because of the map to be `_yitem`.

Okay, that was a bunch of confusing steps in their own right, so let's line up the results:

```
type OuterLambda = _xtype -> _ytype -> MapRet
x :: _yitem -> _outeritem
type MapRet = [_outeritem]
y :: YArg -> [_yitem]
type YArg = (_outeritem -> _lret) -> _yitem -> _lret
y :: ((_outeritem -> _lret) -> _yitem -> _lret) -> [_yitem]
```

Progress! This has names for every type to and from `x` and `y`. But our expression is a lambda, so we must accept those two:

```
(_yitem -> _outeritem) -> 
(((_outeritem -> _lret) -> _yitem -> _lret) -> [_yitem]) ->
[_outeritem]
```

That's one very long type. Let's compare it to the compiler inferred type that Yuji Yamamoto showed us:

```
(a0 -> b0) -> 
(((b0 -> c0) -> a0 -> c0) -> [a0]) -> 
[b0]
```

It matches. We have here quite a few orders of function: the expression expects functions `x` and `y`, and `y` expects a function that itself takes a `l` function. And all of the types we do have names for may in turn be arbitrarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

Annotating intentionally wrong type (often `()`) would help you.
For example:

```
> (\x y -> map x (y (. x))) :: ()

<interactive>:1:2: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘()’
                  with actual type ‘(a0 -> b0)
                                    -> (((b0 -> c0) -> a0 -> c0) -> [a0]) -> [b0]’
    • The lambda expression ‘\ x y -> map x (y (. x))’
      has two arguments,
      but its type ‘()’ has none
      In the expression: (\ x y -> map x (y (. x))) :: ()
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (\ x y -> map x (y (. x))) :: ()
```

This tip is introduced in this post: http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/05/19/ghcid_for_the_win.html

Comment: I actually want to solve this problem using pen and paper

Comment: Why not just type `:t \x y -> map x (y (. x))`?

Comment: It's an exercise that I'm trying to understand

Comment: I tend to use `_` for a type hole; GHC then reports the inferred type in a "Found type wildcard" message. PartialTypeSignatures makes it a warning instead of a compile error.

Comment: @Highness That is indeed useful. Mark's point is that giving an intentionally incorrect type is just a needlessly roundabout way of asking for the type directly.