# How does the type inference algorithm resolve guarded equations?

Tags: haskell

I tried to find out how Haskell is able to resolve types from a guarded equation where no type is specified through the web.

Like in e.g. following function definition, ghci is able to resolve the type and tells me exactly what it is.

```
fun a b c
| a == c = b
| b < 0 = a+b
| otherwise = c
```

How does it do this? I know how this works for if-then-else constructs  (basically: start with generic version, add constraints) but I am wondering which extra steps are needed here?

Comment: Guards are sort of like if/then/else anyway, at least conceptually, so I'm not sure why you think something extra is in need of explanation here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What part of Hindley-Milner do you not understand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12532552/791604).

Comment: Guards can be in fact be understood as simply _syntactic sugar_ for `if`-expressions (which in turn can be reduced to `case`, which also allows for pattern guards). GHC actually typechecks before all desugaring, but that's an implementation detail and mostly done to get better error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun` has three arguments and a result. So initially the compiler assumes they might each be a different type:

```
fun :: alpha -> beta -> gamma -> delta         -- the type vars are placeholders
```

Ignoring the guards, look at the rhs result of the equations: they each must be type `delta`. So set up a series of type-level equations from the term-level equations. Use `~` between types to say they must be the same.

- The first equation has result `b`, so `b`'s type must be same as the result, i.e. `beta ~ delta`.
- The third equation has result `c`, so `c`'s type must be the same as the result, `gamma ~ delta`.
- The second equation has rhs `+` operator `:: Num a => a -> a -> a`. We'll come back to the `Num a =>`. This is saying `+` has two arguments and a result, all of which are same type. That type is the result of `fun`'s rhs so must be `delta`. The second arg to `+` is `b`, so `b`'s type must be same as the result, `beta ~ delta`. We already had that from the first equation, so this is just confirming consistency.
- The first arg to `+` is `a`, so `a`'s type must be same again, `alpha ~ delta`.

We have `alpha ~ beta ~ gamma ~ delta`. So go back to the initial signature (which was as general as possible), and substitute equals for equals:

```
fun :: (constraints) => alpha -> alpha -> alpha -> alpha
```

**Constraints**

Pick those up on the fly from the operators.

- We already saw `Num` because of operator `+`.
- The first equation's `a == c` gives us `Eq`.
- The second equation's `b < 0` gives us `Ord`.
- Actually the appearance of `0` gives us another `Num`, because `0 :: Num a => a`, and `< :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` IOW the arguments to `<` must be same type and same constraints.

So pile up those constraints at the front of `fun`'s type, eliminating duplicates

```
fun :: (Num alpha, Eq alpha, Ord alpha) => alpha -> alpha -> alpha -> alpha
```

Is that what you're favourite compiler is telling you? It's probably using type variable `a` rather than `alpha`. It's probably not showing `Eq alpha`.

**Eliminating unnecessary superclass constraints**

```
Main> :i Ord
...
class Eq a => Ord a where
...
```

The `Eq a =>` is telling every `Ord` type must come with an `Eq` already. So in giving the signature for `fun`, the compiler is assuming away its `Eq`.

```
fun :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> a
```

QED

Comment: Thank you for the detailed QED! This helps me understanding how type inference works in Haskell in general a lot better. I assume that guards and if/then/else constructs are handled equivalent implicitly according to type inference.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun a b c
| a == c = b
| b < 0 = a+b
| otherwise = c
```

Is it clear how this translates to if/else?

```
fun a b c
 = if a == c
      then b
      else if b < 0
             then a+b
             else c
```

And if we add some human-readable annotations:

```
fun a b c      -- Start reasoning with types of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `result :: r`
 = if a == c   -- types `a` and `c` are equal,  aka `a ~ c`.  Also `Eq a, Eq c`.
      then b   -- types `b ~ r`
      else if b < 0   -- `Num b, Ord b`
             then a+b -- `a ~ b ~ r` and `Num a, Num b`
             else c   -- `c ~ r`
```

If you take all these facts together the type boils down pretty quickly.

```
a ~ b ~ r  and c ~ r
```

So we know there's actually only one type which we'll just call `a` and rename all the other types variables in the facts.

```
Num a, Eq a, Ord a
```

As a small cognitive savings we know `Ord` implies `Eq` so we can end up with constraints `Num a, Ord a`.

All that swept the mechanics - leveraging of implications such as `(==) t1 t2 ~~> t1 = t2` - under the rug but hopefully in an acceptable fashion.

Comment: Looking at your workings, I rather think the nesting for `if-then-else` makes it harder to see the program's logic or its type inference. That applies especially if there are type errors: the compiler will point to the errors in the guards source lines, not to the desugarred version.

Comment: @AntC I don't understand what you're getting at.  The asker mentioned they know how type inference works in the face of if-then-else so I merely sought to show how guards don't require any additional knowledge wrt type checking.  I wasn't advocating replacing guards in real programs or as a naive compilation step.